# jQuery: Using web storage/local storage on input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, web-storage

I am trying so save/retrieve the values of all input fields in a form. Unfortunately, this is not working.
The frustrating part is that I have *no idea* whats wrong. I already tested for type: both key and value are strings. The event is attached properly, a `console.log` gets triggered.
Do you see anything that strikes you in this code? Why are no values saved or retrieved?

```
(function ($) {
    if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
        $.each($("#myform input[type=text]"), function () {
            localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        $("#myform input[type=text]").live("change", function () {
            localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Of course I am testing in a browser that supports web storage and every input has an id.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: Please put it in jsfiddle. and show html content also.

Comment: @TusharGupta I am using jQuery version 1.8.3.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E5qNH/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.live()` is removed in 1.9 and deprecated from 1.7
2. I don't see any value setter `$(this).val(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")))` in the first `each` loop to populate values.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem – how stupid of me! I retrieved the value but simply did not enter it as value!

Answer (score 1):

*As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*

(from JQuery documentation)

So my guess is that you have two options:

```
$("#myform input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
 });
```

or

```
$("#myform input[type=text]").delegate("change", function () {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
 });
```